# Meaning of どんだけお人好しなんですかって話ですよね

Tags: meaning, particle-って

context (a guy talking to himself while someone else is listening):

> 銀行が住宅ローンの営業に熱心な理由ってわかります？
> 憧れの持ち家を手に入れた大切なお客さんの喜ぶ笑顔が見たいから…？
> そんなわけねーです！
> どんだけお人好しなんですかって話ですよね。儲かるからに決まってます

This usage seems to have similarities to ってこと. My intuition would be that it basically sums up what he's saying as the question that って is quoting with the implication that anyone who believes the second line is a お人好し.

Comment: This is not the answer for your question, but 「そんなわけねーです！」part sounds very unnatural. ねー（ない） is a bit offensive and annoyed expression, usually followed by 「やろ,やろう, やろー」so 「そんなわけねーやろう！」or just 「そんなわけねー！」sounds more natural.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you have got the gist of the phrase.

> 「どんだけ～～って話{はなし}ですよね / だよね / だよな, etc.。」

has been a very common informal/colloquial phrase expressing one's surprise at something one has seen, heard, etc.

The dictionary form of 「どんだけ」 is, of course, 「どれだけ ("how", "how much", etc.)」, which is used in exclamations.

**The 「って」 is quotative**.  Important thing is to **not** translate the 「話」 part literally into "story" in your head.  「話」 here means more like 「こと」 and it only emphasizes what you want to say.

> 「どんだけお[人好]{ひとよ}しなんですかって話ですよね。」 =
>
> 「『どんだけお人好しなんですか？』って話ですよね。」 =
>
> "How credulous could one get?", I'd say, wouldn't you?

Who is being talked about?  It is those who believe that banks are eager to issue housing loans because they truly love to see the happy smiles on their customers' faces for finally acquiring their dream homes.

Comment: lol There is even a Wiki page for 「どんだけ～」!  I said to myself just that upon finding it, too.  I said "it has been popular" in my answer because I do not remember hearing it when I was younger.  http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%A9%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%80%9C