# みすぎって in the phrase 韓国たのしみすぎって話

Tags: meaning, parsing

> 韓国たのしみすぎって話！

How would you translate this? "Talk that Korea is too much fun!" ?

話 is the verb, why is it not conjugated?

Should I interpret って as indirect speech particle, or colloquial topic marker?

Why たのし instead of 楽しい?

みすぎ means "too much", should I view this as a noun?

Comment: Here's a hint:  You're parsing it wrong.  It is (韓国)(たのしみ(すぎ))(って話).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- 楽しみ in this sentence means "is going to be fun", "can't wait", etc. 韓国が楽しみです means "I'm looking forward to (visiting) Korea".
- すぎ literally means "too much", but in this context it's a bit slangy way of saying "soooo", "super", etc.
- This って is a colloquial equivalent of という. I think you have gotten this right.
- ～って話だ or ～という話だ in this context is an exclamatory expression used to emphasize your feeling. Semantically it's like "you know (what)". See: [Meaning of どんだけお人好しなんですかって話ですよね](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21064/5010)

So the whole sentence just means "You know what, I'm soooo excited about (visiting) Korea!"

Answer (score 0):

After some research I am (sort of) confident that たのしみ = 楽しみ should be translated with "looking forward to". Translating すぎ as "too (much)" we get

"too (much) looking forward to" as in "very much looking forward to"

All in all, I am picturing a situation where a group of people is waiting for their flight to Korea and they're talking about how much they're excited for the trip.

> Talk(ing) about so looking forward to (visiting) Korea!

Answer (score -1):

Correct, って is a semi-colloquial connector if you will.
In Japanese って is used in place of と nowadays in a colloquial way.
と and って are used to refer/accent the action that follows.
For example, 勉強しろって言われた - I was told to study. The って in this case refers to the 言われた - was told.
Normally the professional way of saying that would be 勉強しろと言われました but among friends or family people usually revert to 勉強しろって言われた.

I don't know if that helps but here's hoping lol

Comment: I think that って here means という rather than と.  Your examples have the verb 言われる, but the OP's example has the noun 話.

Comment: My mistake, という would be what it's replacing. But either a verb or noun, the って being a colloquial conjunctive particle (or dependency marker) referring to the action/topic of the sentence would still stand no?

Comment: `the って being a colloquial conjunctive particle...` -- The って is a 格助詞(case particle), not a 接続助詞(conjunctive particle). The case particle って has two meanings: ①引用を表す/quotative (≂と), ②同格を表す/appositive (≂という). (sources: 明鏡国語辞典 and [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/147762/meaning/m0u/って/)) Your post explains #1, but the って in the OP is #2.