# Usage of という話に。。。

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'm reading a manga where the character is shocked at how quickly he has leveled up. He says:

> ただ。。。ありえないほど伸びてる。。。これじゃあ僕のこれまでの半月は一体何だったんだ**という話に。。。**

I'm interested in this usage of ending a sentence with という話に but I'm uncertain on the meaning. Is this a common pattern? Should we assume the ellipsis/missing words implies something along the lines of という話になるだろう ?

And is it accurate to translate this roughly as:

> It's just... I'm growing an insane amount... Now people will be talking about what the hell I've been up to this past half month.

Basically does the 話 here mean the character will be the subject of talk by other people?

Comment: I don't think it necessarily has to mean "people will talk about it". My understanding is something along the lines of "it's like...", "isn't it like...", "the situation will become..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's short for ～という話になる(だろう), which is a colloquial set phrase that means "amounts to ～", "would effectively mean ～", "leads to the conclusion that ～", or something like these. In other words, it's almost the same as [～ということになる](https://www.easyjapanesee.com/%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82).

> これじゃあ僕のこれまでの半月は一体何だったんだという話に(なる)。
>
> It makes me wonder what the hell I've been up to this past half month.
> It effectively means my efforts for the last half month have been meaningless.

～という話だ is used in the same way. Do not take this 話 too literally. See also: [Meaning of どんだけお人好しなんですかって話ですよね](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21064/5010) / [みすぎって in the phrase 韓国たのしみすぎって話](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57726/5010)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So it seems like という話 can be used in a similar way to ということ or というわけ in explaining a meaning or conclusion? Also, do you think this would be an acceptable translation of the sentence: "So it begs the question... what the hell have I been up to the past half month?!"

Comment: @skywalker It's acceptable but maybe a bit too verbose. 話になる is a fairly common phrase that can happen casually in everyday speech.